# How to find dll/so files in a CMake Superbuild

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cmake, cross-platform

I have set up cross-platform software project using CMake Superbuild, where dependencies are added and built using `ExternalProject_Add`. The project compiles on both Windows and Linux, but when I try to run the executable programs that are produced, it does not work because it fails to find dll/so files of dependencies. This is not surprising, as the dll/so files of external dependencies are not placed in the output directory(`bin` in visualization below).

One of the dependencies that are added using `ExternalProject_Add` is OpenCV. After OpenCv is built by the superbuild, I can find it using `find_package(OpenCv)`. I can then reference libraries and include files by using the variables `OpenCV_LIBS` and `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS`. However, there seems to be no variables that tell me where the dll/so files are located.

To further complicate it, it seems that the dll/so files end up in different folders when building on Linux and Windows. Here is simplified visualization of my project structure. `Build/bin` is where my executable programs and dll/so files that my project produces end up.

`|-- Project1
|   |-- Source1.cpp
|-- Project2
|   |-- Source2.cpp
|-- CMake
|   |-- Superbuild.cmake
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- Build
|       |-- External_projects
|       |-- Bin`

On Windows, the OpenCV dlls end up in the `external_projects` folder: `external_projects/OpenCV-build/bin/Debug`, wheras on Linux the .so files end up in `external_projects/OpenCV-build/lib`.

I guess I could for each external project check where the dll/so files end up, and copy them by using a combination of GLOB and `if(WIN32)` etc. But this doesn't seem ideal.

What is the proper way of doing this in a CMake superbuild, how do you make the dll/so files available so the executable programs can find them?

**Update**
To clarify: There is a CMakeLists.txt file inside the CMake folder. This script calls Superbuild.cmake which (somewhat simplified) looks like this:

`ExternalProject_Add(OpenCV ...) # Downloads source from github
ExternalProject_Add(libtiff...)# Downloads source from gitlab
...
ExternalProject_Add(myMainProject
   SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/.. # Adds CMakeLists.txt in root project folder 
    DEPENDS ${myMainProjectDependencies} # OpenCV and libtiff
)`

This results in the dependencies being built before myMainProject is built.

Comment: `find_package(OpenCV)` runs **either** script `FindOpenCV.cmake` **or** script `OpenCVConfig.cmake`. The first one should be shipped by you, and exactly this script is responsible to locate things both on Linux and Windows. The second script comes with OpenCV installation and it already contains exact paths corresponded to particular installation. Which case is yours?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Right after calling `ExternalProject_Add` for OpenCV I have defined OpenCV_DIR to the folder where OpenCV is built. When building OpenCV it creates a file called OpenCVConfig.cmake, so I assume that is the one being used.

Comment: "Right after calling `ExternalProject_Add` for OpenCV I have defined OpenCV_DIR" - What do you mean by "after"? In the next line of `CMakeLists.txt` script? Note, that  `find_package` doesn't work with project, added via `ExternalProject_Add`  in the **same project**: `find_package` looks for files immediately (at *configuration* stage), but commands specified in `ExternalProject_Add` are performed only at a *build* stage. It is actually not clear what do you mean by "superbuild": Is this is just a top-level project, or this is a project which builds all others via `ExternalProject_Add`.

Comment: Yes, that was probably a bit unclear. This is a two-step process. So when find_package runs, OpenCV has already been built. The variable OpenCV_DIR is sent as an argument to the CMakeLists.txt script that builds my project, and I guess that is how find_package knows to call OpenCVConfig.cmake. My project is set up in a way similar to https://github.com/MITK/MITK

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have updated my original question with more details on how the project and its dependencies are built.

Comment: "it does not work because it fails to find dll/so files of dependencies." - The **exact error message** would explain the problem clearer than all further text...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202653/discussion-between-larsjr-and-tsyvarev).

Answer (score 1):

You can setup an install target with CMake, and configure it to place your binaries and headers in the correct location:

```
# bin
if (${BUILD_SHARED_LIBS})
    install(
        FILES
            $<TARGET_FILE:my_target>
        DESTINATION
            bin
        COMPONENT
            runtime
    )
endif()

# lib
install(
    TARGETS
        my_target
    DESTINATION
        lib
    COMPONENT
        devel
)

# include
install(
    FILES
        Header1.hpp
        Header2.hpp
    DESTINATION
        include/my_target
    COMPONENT
        devel
)
```

Now you can install the binaries, import libraries, and headers to your `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` path, using something like `ninja install` (assuming you're using Ninja as the generator for CMake).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this needs to be added to the external project's CMakeLists.txt? What would you do when you can't control the external project's CMakelists.txt? To continue using OpenCV as an example, I tried passing `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../bin` but then it ended up creating `bin`, `include` and `lib` folders inside my `bin` folder. So my program executables ended up in `bin` (or actually `bin/Debug` when using Visual Studio, and dlls from external cmake ended up in `bin/bin`

Comment: @larsjr have you tried using an absolute path for `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, my example was a bit unclear. I did try with an absolute path. The problem is that it did not place dll files directly in my bin folder, but rather a new bin folder was created. I guess I can set up CMake to copy all files from `bin/bin` to `bin`.

Comment: @larsjr I'm not familiar with OpenCV, but it appears they configure a `OPENCV_BIN_INSTALL_PATH` variable internally (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/search?p=1&q=OPENCV_BIN_INSTALL_PATH&unscoped_q=OPENCV_BIN_INSTALL_PATH).