# Correct way to build OpenCV as a third party library along with your project in CMAKE

Tags: c++, opencv, build, cmake

I have a C++ project, where I use opencv, VTK. I would like to build and install these dependent libraries (opencv,vtk) automatically, which are situated in my thirdparty project folder. I know that opencv and VTK use cmake build system to build their libraries. I even saw the function **ExternalProject** to add them to my *CMakesLists.txt* but I had problem of linking the target with opencv libs.

Searching on stack overflow I could not find a proper defined method to do it to implement this for version 3.0, the proposed solutions where Version < 3.0.  I would like to know how you will structure your project to build opencv automatically as a thirdparty library, exports its targets and link it with my project target.

Comment: Do you use modified versions of VTK/OpenCV?

Comment: I just took the source from their GIT repo. All I want to do is add the source my third party folder and make it build and link it to my executable.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is to look for what's being done on larger project on github. I would advise to look at [this repo](https://github.com/IbisNeuronav/Ibis) in which they use opencv version 3.2, automatically download it and compile it. I believe that this is the correct way because you just have to change the version to try the compatibility with the newer versions if you want to update your code.
What you are looking for is probably what is called a superbuild. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58933367/how-to-find-dll-so-files-in-a-cmake-superbuild) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to build and install opencv in a subfolder of your repo or your build directory. Then you could set the `OpenCV_DIR` environment variable to the `<opencv_install_prefix>/lib/cmake/opencv4` folder (or at least point to the folder where `OpenCVConfig.cmake` is)

Then in your `CMakeLists.txt` you can directly use :

```
find_package(OpenCV 4 REQUIRED
  COMPONENTS core imgproc ximgproc)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

The `OpenCV_DIR` variable tells CMake where to find the OpenCV configuration files needed for `find_package` function.

For the build and installation step, you could use `ExternalProject` or `FetchContent` (I prefer the later) but since OpenCV could be very long to build, you might want to keep the build artifact outside of your project's build folder. Then you can erase your build folder to rebuild your project without rebuilding the whole OpenCV library.
On my side, I'm using a shell script that build OpenCV if needed before building the project that needs it.